# Insert period before uppercase characters

Tags: bash, filenames, uppercase

I have files whose names I want to change.

Example:

```
HawaiiFive02010SXXEXXW.ac3
Nashville2012SXXEXXW.ac3
HowToGetAwayWithMurderSXXEXXW.ac3
BetterCallSaulSXXEXXW.ac3
BeautyAndTheBeast2012SXXEXXW.ac3
```

I need to convert them:

```
Nashville.2012.SXXEXX.W.ac3
How.To.Get.Away.With.Murder.SXXEXX.W.ac3
Better.Call.Saul.SXXEXX.W.ac3
Beauty.And.The.Beast.2012.SXXEXX.W.ac3
Hawaii.Five.0.2010.SXXEXX.W.ac3
```

I found this :

```
echo Nashville2012SXXEXXW.ac3 | sed 's/[A-Z]/.&/g;s/^.//'
Nashville2012.SXX.EXX.W.ac3
echo HowToGetAwayWithMurderSXXEXXW.ac3 | sed 's/[A-Z]/.&/g;s/^.//'
How.To.Get.Away.With.Murder.SXX.EXX.W.ac3
```

If it is not possible to change the file names I would call them myself. I just want to know if this would be potentially possible to find a way but if it's too complicated I do spend since the rest of the script works :)

Comment: I get `echo Nashville2012SXXEXXW.ac3 | sed 's/[A-Z]/.&/g;s/^.//'
Nashville2012.S.X.X.E.X.X.W.ac3` (as I would expect). Please post  your real data. AND Getting `Nashville.2012`. won't be easy. Good luck.

Comment: You need to be more precise about what you want.  The title asks for dots before uppercase letters, but in the HawaiiFive0 example you don't put dots before the Xs and the E, and you put a hyphen before the first 0.

Comment: @pjh To be fair, I edited the title, but before it was "BASH Replace uppercase of String of characters with a point and uppercase", which doesn't point out that it should only be the first of a group of uppercase characters either.

Comment: @pjh i change hyphen with a dots

Comment: @Saber Pendragon, thanks for the update, but it still is not clear precisely what you want.  Why is there a dot before the first 0 and the 2, which are not uppercase letters, and why are there no dots before the Xs and the E?

Comment: @pjh I guess the `SXXEXX` are actually season and episodes numbers, so the really look like `S01E05`, for example, but this circes back to showing *real* input and not simplifications that introduce inaccuracies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed :

```
sed -r 's/([A-Z][^A-Z.]+)/\1./g;s/[0-9]{4}/.&/g;s/([0-9])([0-9]{4})[^$]/\1.\2./;s/SXXEXXW/SXXEXX.W/;s/(S[0-9][0-9])\./\1/'
```

Example :

```
$ echo Nashville2012SXXEXXW.ac3 | sed -r 's/([A-Z][^A-Z.]+)/\1./g;s/[0-9]{4}/.&/g;s/([0-9])([0-9]{4})[^$]/\1.\2./;s/SXXEXXW/SXXEXX.W/;s/(S[0-9][0-9])\./\1/'
Nashville.2012.SXXEXX.W.ac3

$ echo HowToGetAwayWithMurderSXXEXXW.ac3 | sed -r 's/([A-Z][^A-Z.]+)/\1./g;s/[0-9]{4}/.&/g;s/([0-9])([0-9]{4})[^$]/\1.\2./;s/SXXEXXW/SXXEXX.W/;s/(S[0-9][0-9])\./\1/'
How.To.Get.Away.With.Murder.SXXEXX.W.ac3

$ echo HawaiiFive02010S03E08W.ac3 | sed -r 's/([A-Z][^A-Z.]+)/\1./g;s/[0-9]{4}/.&/g;s/([0-9])([0-9]{4})[^$]/\1.\2./;s/SXXEXXW/SXXEXX.W/;s/(S[0-9][0-9])\./\1/'
Hawaii.Five.0.2010.S03E08.W.ac3
```

Comment: Nice ! Big thanks :D ! but `echo Nashville2012S03E18W.ac3 | sed -r 's/([A-Z][^A-Z.]+)/\1./g;s/[0-9]{4}/.&/g;s/([0-9])([0-9]{4})[^$]/\1.\2./;s/SXXEXXW/SXXEXX.W/'
Nashville.2012.S03.E18.W.ac3 and not Nashville.2012.S03E18.W.ac3`

Comment: Updated. `SXXEXX` is not `S03E18`. Thats's what was pointed out in your comments by Benjamin W.

Comment: Yes sorry for inaccuracies buy thanks ! Merci infiniment :) !

Comment: I have a little problems witch NCIS
`echo NCISS13E11W.aac |sed -r 's/([A-Z][^A-Z.]+)/\1./g;s/[0-9]{4}/.&/g;s/([0-9])([0-9]{4})[^$]/\1.\2./;s/SXXEXXW/SXXEXX.W/;s/(S[0-9][0-9])\./\1/'
NCISS13E11.W.aac`
`echo NCISNewOrleansS02E11W.aac |sed -r 's/([A-Z][^A-Z.]+)/\1./g;s/[0-9]{4}/.&/g;s/([0-9])([0-9]{4})[^$]/\1.\2./;s/SXXEXXW/SXXEXX.W/;s/(S[0-9][0-9])\./\1/'
NCISNew.Orleans.S02E11.W.aac`
And for 
`echo NCISLosAngelesS02E11W.aac |sed -r 's/([A-Z][^A-Z.]+)/\1./g;s/[0-9]{4}/.&/g;s/([0-9])([0-9]{4})[^$]/\1.\2./;s/SXXEXXW/SXXEXX.W/;s/(S[0-9][0-9])\./\1/'
NCISLos.Angeles.S02E11.W.aac
`
Need a little help

Comment: With NCISNewOrleansS02E11W.ac3, NCISS13E11W.ac3, NCISLosAngelesS07E12W.ac3 and LawAndOrderSVUS17E07W.ac3, don't work :( The result is : Law.And.Order.SVUS17E07.W.ac3, NCISNew.Orleans.S02E11.W.aac Many thanks for answer @Kenavoz